# 'openssl verify' outputs 'unable to get local issuer certificate'

Tags: debian, ssl-certificate, installation, certificate, openssl

In /etc/ssl, when I do `sudo openssl verify mywebsite.pem`  I get a message stating

```
    mywebsite.pem: OU = GT46830179, OU = See www.rapidssl.com/resources/cps (c)15, OU = Domain Control Validated - RapidSSL(R), CN = *.logitapp.com
error 20 at 0 depth lookup:unable to get local issuer certificate
```

I created mywebsite.key by copying from sslpoint's certificate generator into nano. I created mywebsite.pem by running `sudo cat mywebsite.crt sslpointintermediate.crt >> mywebsite.pem` . Created mywebsite.crt and sslpointintermediate.crt by pasting into nano from the email [sslpoint](https://www.sslpoint.com/) sent me.

mywebsite.pem and mywebsite.key aren't actually the names of the files.

Using Debian 8. Trying to get nginx and gunicorn working with ssl. Having problems with that and I think it's (at least partially) because the ssl certificates somehow aren't installed correctly, as indicated by the above output. How can I resolve this?

EDIT:

In a previous version of this question I was also asking about 'openssl verify'ing the .key file. I've removed that part of the question as there's no point in trying that.

Answer (score 10):

If you want to use `openssl verify`, you should instead use:

```
openssl verify -CAfile your-intermediates-and-final.pem mywebsite.crt
```

with your-intermediates-and-final.pem with all intermediate and final (trusted anchor) concatenated inside, in PEM format. If you want to use the `-CApath /etc/ssl/certs` option, each intermediate certificate must be in the /etc/ssl/certs directory and you must execute as root:

```
$ c_rehash
```

---

nginx seems to be correctly configured. Verify the permissions are correct and you have the two following config parameters in your `server {}` or `http {}` section:

```
ssl_certificate /path/to/your/mywebsite.pem;
ssl_certificate_key /path/to/your/mywebsite.key;
```

and in your `server {}` section:

```
listen 443 ssl;
```

---

EDIT - this was a part of answer to the original question:

The key only contains the private key and no certificate, so there is no point in "openssl verify"ing it.

Comment: Thanks. It outputs OK when I do 'sudo openssl verify -verbose -CAfile /usr/share/ca-certificates/extra/CACertificate-1.cer -untrusted sslpointintermediate.crt mywebsite.pem' . Is there a reason I might want to use -CApath? Do I need to install sslpointintermediate.crt or CACertificate-1.cer somewhere/somehow? SSLPoint let me download CACertificate-1/2.cer and ServerCertificate.cer. I tried following askubuntu.com/questions/73287/… previously but it didn't add anything. My nginx has that in it. What would the correct permissions (for ?) be?

Comment: OpenSSL command line tools are intended only to perform small tasks. I don’t use to use them, apart to create keys and certificates and read existing certs, but never to verify cert chains -- instead I install the certs on nginx and it generally works. For nginx you only have to put in one (PEM) file: the server cert, then the first intermediate cert, the second intermediate cert, etc, and optionnally the root certificate; and the server key in a separate file. You can make these two files owned by root with permissions 600.

Comment: If you add a CA cert to /etc/ssl/certs (or wherever the CAs certs go), then remember to run the c_rehash program as root.

Answer (score 3):

OpenSSL only needs to be run as root when it needs to read private data as private keys in `/etc/ssl/private/`. For certificate verification, root is not needed. Certificates in `/etc/ssl/certs` should be readable by everyone in order every user and software can verify certificates. Or do you enter root password every time you call a website?

```
$ openssl verify mywebsite.pem
mywebsite.pem: OU = GT46830179, OU = See www.rapidssl.com/resources/cps (c)15, OU = Domain Control Validated - RapidSSL(R), CN = *.logitapp.com
error 20 at 0 depth lookup:unable to get local issuer certificate
```

Looking at the manpage of verify(1ssl):

```
   2 X509_V_ERR_UNABLE_TO_GET_ISSUER_CERT: unable to get issuer certificate
       the issuer certificate of a looked up certificate could not be found. This normally means the list of trusted certificates is not complete.
```

You need to give openssl some informations about where in the chain the certificates are needed:

```
openssl verify [-CApath directory] [-CAfile file] [-untrusted file] [certifictes]
```

For example:

```
openssl verify -CAfile RootCert.pem -untrusted Intermediate.pem UserCert.pem
```

See also [this question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25482199/2851664)

---

```
$ openssl verify mywebsite.key I get a message saying
unable to load certificate
139893743232656:error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line:pem_lib.c:703:Expecting: TRUSTED CERTIFICATE
```

The certificate could not be loaded, as you gave a private key. This is the opposite of a certificate, which holds the public key with additional information about the certificate chain, validity etc. The error message clearly says, what is expected: `Expecting: TRUSTED CERTIFICATE`

---

You only need to "install" a root certificate if it is not already trusted by your OS and you want it to be trusted. But as you talk about servers, there's no point in including your own domain's certificate in the trust store. Your software (nginx) in this case, needs to have access to a certificate file including the full trust chain, from the leaf certificate of your domain up to the root certificate of your CA (optional).

Please see either the nginx's documentation, look for other questions of this kind (the internet including SE and SF) is full of it or give an exact and detailed description of your problem.

Comment: Thanks. It outputs OK when I do 'sudo openssl verify -verbose -CAfile /usr/share/ca-certificates/extra/CACertificate-1.cer -untrusted sslpointintermediate.crt mywebsite.pem' .  I don't understand your question about the root password but it gives me a permission denied message when I don't use sudo. Do I need to install sslpointintermediate.crt or CACertificate-1.cer somewhere/somehow? SSLPoint let me download CACertificate-1/2.cer and ServerCertificate.cer. I tried following http://askubuntu.com/questions/73287/how-do-i-install-a-root-certificate previously but it didn't add anything.

Comment: @Daniel I added information about permissions of certificates, and where the certificate chain needs to be used.

Answer (score 2):

you have must ***cat*** all certs to final CA_Chain.crt:

cat RootCA.crt IntermediateCert1 IntermediateCert2 > CA_Chain.crt

openssl verify -CAfile CA_Chain.crt website.crt

(website.crt sign by IntermediateCert2)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like awscli uses your system local openssl to verify the certificates.
On my mac I have openssl version 0.9.8 and I was unable to verify my certificate.
You can check the version of your openssl by writing command

```
openssl version
```

I switched to a system containing openssl version 0.10 and it fixed the issue.
You can also upgrade your openssl version as well.

I tried uploading the certificate again and it worked for me.